# construct test environment for web application on PC - directory issues

Tags: php, apache, path, test-environments

I have a site that physically has this directory structure.

```
-public_html
--conf     > contains file conf.php 
-SiteFiles
-LiveSite > contains file ConfLive.php
```

Directory public_html/conf/ contains a file called conf.php

this file contains the following include

```
include_once('/home/mydir/SiteFiles/LiveSite/conf/ConfLive.iphp');
```

I want to copy this application to test PC to test it.
Test PC uses XAMPP Apache.
"Root" directory on the test machine is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

My questions:
1. Where is logical path "`/home/mydir/" defined`?
2. What steps should I take to get this to work on my test machine preferably by server configuration and not changing application.

Thanks.
(PS maybe this question is better posed at Server Overflow site.)

Comment: Why are you using absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] as the document root.

Comment: I would like to avoid changing the application, plus I fix one and I keep finding more.